# Unable to add text to JTextArea in Java from another function

Tags: java, function, static, actionlistener, jtextarea

I made a simple program in Java that contains only one text area and a button. The button is suppose to add a "text". However, it doesn't work for me.

*On a side note: I'm trying to keep my functions as short as possible. (I don't want a function with too many line of codes)*

First, I create the JFrame

```
private static void createFrame()
{
    //Build JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Frame");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(500,400);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(textScrollPane());
    contentPane.add(buttonAddText());

    //Set Frame Visible
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

Then the TextArea and the Scrollpane (for adding scrollbar)

```
private static JTextArea textArea()
{
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
    output.setLineWrap(true); // Text return to line, so no horizontal scrollbar
    output.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    output.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    return output;
}

private static JScrollPane textScrollPane()
{
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(textArea());
    scrollPane2.setBounds(0, 0, 490, 250);

    return scrollPane2;
}
```

And finally, the button

```
private static JButton buttonAddText()
{
    JButton testbutton = new JButton("TEST");
    testbutton.setBounds(20, 280, 138, 36);

    testbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //action listener here
            textArea().insert("TEXT",0);
            System.out.println("Button Tested!");
        }
    });

    return testbutton;
}
```

When I click on the button, it doesn't do anything.
I just want a text to be added in the JTextArea. Did I forget something?

Comment: How about you don't use static. Static is not a cross object communication mechanism. Instead, provide a model or reference to the objects you need updated to the other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textArea() is returning a new JTextArea everytime it is called. Therefore your buttonAddText() function is calling textArea() and adding text to a newly created text area that is not contained in the scroll pane.

You need to pass a reference of the text area to the textScrollPane() and the buttonAddText() functions.

Something like this would work:

```
JTextArea jta = textArea();
contentPane.add(textScrollPane(jta));
contentPane.add(buttonAddText(jta));
```

Change textScrollPane() and buttonAddText() so that they accept a JTextArea parameter and don't call textArea() in these functions anymore to create new text areas. Instead use the JTextArea object which is passed into the functions.

Comment: I did what you said and then, I also added "final JTextArea" for my buttonAddText() function and it works! Thank you very much.